# React Native SectionList: What are the correct TypeScript types

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-typings, typescript-types, react-native-sectionlist

I'm building a React Native app using TypeScript. I'm trying to use a [`SectionList`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist). I followed the docs, and here is my code:

```
  renderSectionHeader = ({ section: { title } }: { section: { title: string } }) => (
    <ListItem title={title} />
  );

  render() {
    const { sections } = this.props;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <SectionList
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          sections={[
            {title: 'Title1', data: ['item1', 'item2']},
            {title: 'Title2', data: ['item3', 'item4']},
            {title: 'Title3', data: ['item5', 'item6']},
          ]}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

But the line `renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}` throws the following TSLint Error:

```
[ts]
Type '({ section: { title } }: { section: { title: string; }; }) => Element' is not assignable to type '(info: { section: SectionListData<any>; }) => ReactElement<any> | null'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'info' are incompatible.
    Type '{ section: SectionListData<any>; }' is not assignable to type '{ section: { title: string; }; }'.
      Types of property 'section' are incompatible.
        Type 'SectionListData<any>' is not assignable to type '{ title: string; }'.
          Property 'title' is missing in type 'SectionListData<any>'. [2322]
```

Are the types of `SectionList` broken? Or is the example wrong? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7):

```js
const sections = [
  {title: 'Title1', data: ['item1', 'item2']},
  {title: 'Title2', data: ['item3', 'item4']},
  {title: 'Title3', data: ['item5', 'item6']},
];
```

First you need to define the `Section` type and the `Item` type:

```js
type Item = string;

type Section = {
  title: string;
  data: Item[];
};
```

Now you need to define your `renderItem` function:

```js
const renderItem: SectionListRenderItem<Item, Section> = ({item}) => {
  // return component here
};
```

Comment: Imo, this answer uses the generics as intended. Similarly, you can type the whole list with `SectionList<Item, Section>` as its return type if you're using it as a component.

Comment: For anyone else looking, the renderItem function params will be typed like this:

`renderItem = ({ item }: SectionListRenderItemInfo< Item, Section>) => {}`

Answer (score 4):

This one worked for me:

```
import type { SectionListData } from 'react-native';

interface Section {
    title?: string;
    data: readonly any[];
}

type SectionHeader = (info: { section: SectionListData<YOUR_ARRAY_TYPE, Section> }) => React.ReactElement;

    const renderSectionHeader: SectionHeader = ({ section: { title } }) => {
        return YOUR_HEADER_COMPONENT;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I'a new to TypeScript so this question might not be the best but you can check React Native types here: [React Native Types github](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-native/index.d.ts)

In line 4243 for now you can see this:

```
renderSectionHeader?: (info: { section: SectionListData<ItemT> }) => React.ReactElement<any> | null;
```

This mean that renderSectionHeader property require a function with one argument which is an object with section field of `SectionListData<ItemT>` type.

To get rid of error that you posted, you can do something like this:

```
  renderSectionHeader = ({ section: { title } }: { section: { title: string } }): React.ReactElement<any>=> (<ListItem title={title} />)

  render() {
    const { sections } = this.props;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <SectionList
          keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
          sections={[
            {title: 'Title1', data: ['item1', 'item2']},
            {title: 'Title2', data: ['item3', 'item4']},
            {title: 'Title3', data: ['item5', 'item6']},
          ]}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          renderSectionHeader={({section}: {section: SectionListData<string[]>}) => this.renderSectionHeader(section)}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
```

Hope this is correct and will help you.

EDIT:
If you dont want to provide types during props passing this renderHeader method will be errorless:

```
renderSectionHeader = ({ section }: {section: SectionListData<string[]>}): ReactElement<any> | null => (<Text>{section.title}</Text>)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
interface Data {
...
}

const MySectionList = SectionList as SectionList<Data>;

<MySectionList
...
/>
```

worked for me

Comment: How did your Data look like,

Answer (score 0):

This is the `SectionListData` declaration, so you just need to remove the `title` property, and replace it with `key`, then `TSLint Error` will disappear.

```
export interface SectionBase<ItemT> {
    data: ReadonlyArray<ItemT>;

    key?: string;

    renderItem?: SectionListRenderItem<ItemT>;

    ItemSeparatorComponent?: React.ComponentType<any> | null;

    keyExtractor?: (item: ItemT, index: number) => string;
}

export interface SectionListData<ItemT> extends SectionBase<ItemT> {
    [key: string]: any;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4Boz.png)

Comment: What is ItemT and where do I import it from??

Comment: @DiegoPonciano it's a generic, you have to define it according to your data structure like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464102/3484824

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import {SectionList, SectionListData, SectionListRenderItem, SectionListRenderItemInfo, Text} from 'react-native';

export type Item = string; // <-- Change me

export type Section = {
  title: string;  // <-- Change me
  data: readonly Item[];
}

type ListProps = {
  sections: SectionListData<Item, Section>[],
}

type RenderSectionHeaderArgs = {
  section: SectionListData<Item, Section>
}

const renderSectionItem: SectionListRenderItem<Item> = ({item}) => {
  console.log(item);
  return <Text>{item}</Text>;
};

const renderSectionHeader = ({section: {title, data}}: RenderSectionHeaderArgs) => {
  console.log({title, data});
  return <Text>{title}</Text>;
};

const List: React.FC<ListProps> = ({sections}) => {
  return (
    <SectionList
      sections={sections}
      renderItem={renderSectionItem}
      renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
    />
  );
};

export default List;
```

Answer (score -5):

if you know what types you're using and it's only to avoid the warning you could do:

```
sections={sections as any[]}
```